# css styling forms and choosing heights for inputs, buttons etc

Tags: css

When it comes to form styling inputs, textarea, buttons etc is there a way to calculate the height, paddings or something according to font size maybe ? I want to style a form and i played a bit with heights but i didn't find one to like does it depend on something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want  to look at specifying size in **[em](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_%28typography%29)**

> An em is a unit of width in the field of typography, equal to the
>   currently specified point size. For example, one em in a 16-point
>   typeface is 16 points wide. Therefore, this unit is the same for all
>   typefaces at a given point size.

### [Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/wdUD5/)

You can set the `font-size` of the input, then any related dimension settings in `em`. If you had a `font-size` of say `16px`, 1em=16px, so a `border-width` of `1em` would be 16px wide.

Comment: yeah something like this i'm using in this moment for setting the height of an input field based on the base font size with a multiplier to have it a little bit bigger than the font size used in the input field.

Comment: Dont forget you can also use this in combination with calc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: hah sw4 when i came at the office i stayed a little and added calc function around with fallback :). seems we do things the same :))